# Delphi and Java app - how to read data

Tags: java, delphi, applet

At the following link, there is a finance [FinanceChart app](http://www.netdania.com/Products/live-streaming-currency-exchange-rates/real-time-forex-charts/FinanceChart.aspx?m=c) (also, a screen shot of it is below).

When I interact with the chart I get feedback, for example. I move my mouse around and the data shown in the information box changes, as does the highlighted sections on each axis.

The chart itself is a Java application that is updated every few seconds, rather than just some static jpg or graphic.

Please forgive my ignorance here. My question is basically … how can I read this java app data from Delphi ? Could someone point me in the right direction with regards of what technology I can use from Delphi to access this data ?

My goal is to trigger an alarm, say play some wave file if a certain value is reached.

[image]

Comment: Why did you tag with javascript? Do you want to screenscrape?

Comment: one of the options is to write interpreters both in Java application and in Delphi application so that the chart could be exported from Java application and imported into Delphi application using these interpreters

Comment: Another option (in case if you have access to source code of Java application), then you could implement a simple message system between Java/Delphi over TCP/IP and send either XML or some simple string mappings

Comment: If you have to interact and show data in the same manner as in the java app, then you need to get the protocol involved between the server and the java app. If this site has some kind of API, that should be easy, if not... try to hack the protocol with a packet sniffer, but honestly, that wouldn't be the right path...

Comment: @ David Heffernan. No I'm not after scraping the data ... I can't find any values to scrape. To be blunt, Java / Javascript is one and the same to me. It's just my ignorance of other technologies.

Comment: @Greg M. I don't want to do anything that I shouldn't be doing. I was just hoping to get a value and trigger an alarm if some threshold was reached.

Comment: @Mocialov Boris. Thanks, but I don't have the source code. I visit the site as just an ordinary user.

Comment: @Johnny : Threshold = limit value reached. To get the value, you need a way to fetch it. It's not a matter of language involved nor Delphi, but protocol. Without it, i can't see a reliable way to do what you're looking for. And i don't think that you can interact with a java app if it's not meant to be used like this (java app implementing a socket protocol for example).

Comment: @Johnny well, then there is an API provided by the service: http://www.netdania.com/Products/ServerAPI/ServerAPI.aspx otherwise you are screwed.. One thing that comes to mind is to scrap the data by either getting the values from HTML or i don't know, like taking snapshots and analyzing pics.. but that is close to hacking and also, probably, would not be approved by the service provider

Comment: Javascript is unrelated to Java. I'm still unclear on what the problem is.

Comment: @Mocialov Boris. Thank you. Food for thought.

Comment: @ Greg M, I see what your saying, thank you. Time for a rethink.

Answer (score 3):

The page uses a Java Applet to display the chart, and Applet/server communication over HTTP to communicate with the host.

The raw data can only be extracted by using the exact protocol between your Delphi client and the server as between the applet and the server.

So if there is a public web service API offered which provides the same data, this is the preferred solution.

Comment: I think this is what Greg M was referring to. I'll look into this as my starting point. Thanks.